# update all products all attributes values by clicking on one update button

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, database, multi-vendor

we are using magento multi vendor site.

For single Product we are displaying price, selling price , attributes...etc in vendor account.

we gave an option for vendor to update all the textfields of single product by clicking on one "update" button.

we are using following code for this. its working fine

**Phtml**

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('mp_local_shipping_charge');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "local_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "local[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>
<?php endif; ?>


<input type="hidden" name="localcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="localcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getLocal(); ?>" /> 

<p id="updatedlocal_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>

<button id="local_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
function hideResetLocal(product_id,localold) { 

var qtyId='#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#localcurr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#local_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#local_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valuelocal="#valuelocal_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#local_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valuelocal).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currlocal).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}


function updateFieldLocal(product_id) 
{ 
var localId = '#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#localcurr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedlocal_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldLocal/')?>'; 
$local = $wk_jq(localId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currlocal).val($local); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 

parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
//parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function updateFieldLocalAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_local = $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);    
        $product->setData('mp_local_shipping_charge',$upd_local);
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product,'mp_local_shipping_charge');       

       // $product->setLocal($upd_local);

        $product->save();

        echo $local = $product->getLocal();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

Now we want to provide an option for update all textfields of multiple products by clicking on one "update" button.

Ex: for one product we will edit price , for second we will edit price and qty, for third price, quantity , special price . we edit all textfield values and enter the button "save all".

we are using following code for this , its working fine for price and special price, but not working for custom attribute, where

```
attribute id : mp_local_shipping_charge and attribute label is : Local
```

controller.php

```
public function massupdatesellerproAction(){
      if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $ids= $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_mass_update');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $special= $this->getRequest()->getParam('specialprice');

        $local= $this->getRequest()->getParam('mp_local_shipping_charge');

        foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
    $product->setPrice($price[$key]);
    $product->setSpecialPrice($special[$key]);
    $product->setLocal($mp_local_shipping_charge[$key]);


$product->save();
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully deleted from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your param is `local` in your controller you are calling it `$local= $this->getRequest()->getParam('mp_local_shipping_charge');` ald your attribute code is not more `local`

```
public function massupdatesellerproAction(){
      if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $ids= $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_mass_update');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $special= $this->getRequest()->getParam('specialprice');

        $local= $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');

        foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
    $product->setPrice($price[$key]);
    $product->setSpecialPrice($special[$key]);
    $product->setMpLocalShippingCharge($local[$key]);


$product->save();
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully deleted from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```